# Rebuild .aidl file failed

Tags: android, android-studio

I download the latest Android Studio, open my existing project then I changed one of the data type in a method's argument of my .aidl file.
I clean and rebuild the project like 20 times now, and still I cannot rebuild .aidl and keep throwing:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':playscreen_lib:compileReleaseAidl'.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\Users\ELDORA\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.0\aidl.exe with arguments {-pC:\Users\ELDORA\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-25\framework.aidl -oC:\Users\ELDORA\Documents\Projects\Git\playscreen-v.4\playscreen_lib\build\generated\source\aidl\release -IC:\Users\ELDORA\Documents\Projects\Git\playscreen-v.4\playscreen_lib\src\main\aidl -IC:\Users\ELDORA\Documents\Projects\Git\playscreen-v.4\playscreen_lib\src\release\aidl -IC:\Users\ELDORA.android\build-cache\4492d2ed88e39db806ead472857b23dd46473c28\output\aidl -IC:\Users\ELDORA.android\build-cache\3503095fd81bf51424a6fea93fe733665b5c415d\output\aidl -IC:\Users\ELDORA.android\build-cache\99cfcf1b0afa3f6f8a1f5d9370f6652fdb2c5389\output\aidl -IC:\Users\ELDORA.android\build-cache\d1ed5c0d7925ed8a6207daac53ed47479f327d99\output\aidl -IC:\Users\ELDORA.android\build-cache\b9622378266364961621530394898c10ca07e005\output\aidl -IC:\Users\ELDORA.android\build-cache\ca13b86cac67c820cfadd74657b557d7be41708b\output\aidl -IC:\Users\ELDORA.android\build-cache\1f1034b41fe39b7f222731a1eca43fe985a0c5bf\output\aidl -IC:\Users\ELDORA.android\build-cache\20197f9cb41b0dcfa24d2af19b2f08410bafad05\output\aidl -IC:\Users\ELDORA.android\build-cache\8054d2ad3e9d7b18475122292b9a71c4fd97ce5d\output\aidl -dC:\Users\ELDORA\AppData\Local\Temp\aidl6443722849833229853.d C:\Users\ELDORA\Documents\Projects\Git\playscreen-v.4\playscreen_lib\src\main\aidl\com\playscreen\library\IPlayscreenAPI.aidl}

I never experience this before, it used to be one rebuilt and dependency problem upon changed .aidl will resolves.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer, I guess I can't use java object such as **Long** as method argument, I changed back to **long** and all fine.

I don't know why but they let me pass **String** object but not **Long**. :P